# Node soap client create XML with multiple values for same attribute

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, soap-client

I'm running into an issue with Node soap I feel should be common but I'm not finding anything in the docs or searches.

The XML I'm trying to generate has 4 parameters:

> < customerId xmlns="http...">156668500< /customerId>
>      < mdn xmlns="http...">6204462197< /mdn>
>      < mdn xmlns="http...">6204462198< /mdn>
>      < mdn xmlns="http...">6204462199< /mdn>

Since the soap client only takes a JSON object (not sure about this part but I didn't find a way to pass raw XML and that wouldn't be an optimal solution anyway) I can't just pass the same attribute name (mdn) 3 times. I tried passing it as an array but that wraps each mdn in its own separate tag.
Is there a best practice out there for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this issue recently and found that this is actually supported through arrays.

```
{
  customerId: 156668500,
  mdn: [
    6204462197,
    6204462198,
    6204462198
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building a string and passing that for the client input.

```
var xmlString = '<customerId xmlns="http...">'+request.customerId+'</customerId>'

request.mdn.map(function (mdnValue) {
    xmlString += '<mdn xmlns="http...">'+mdnValue+'</mdn>'; 
});

var xmlObject = {$xml: xmlString};

return resolve(xmlObject);
```

Anyone know a more best-practice type approach?