# How to send raw XML request in node-soap

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, soap-client

I've read the documentation about sending RAW xml request here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#example-with-xml-string-for-the-args

And there is a example at the mentioned documentation:

```
var args = { _xml: "<ns1:MyRootElement xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/v1/ns1">
                        <ChildElement>elementvalue</ChildElement>
                     </ns1:MyRootElement>"
            };
```

I've did the same, and defined my args but I could not get **org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 390; The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.** error message from SOAP server

Here is my args definition:

```
let args = {
        _xml: '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://WSDLPROVIDER" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">'
                + '<SOAP-ENV:Body>'
                    + '<ns1:enqueue>'
                        + '<domain xsi:type="xsd:string">XXXXDOMAINXXXX</domain>'
                            +'<messageBodies SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">'
                            +   '<item xsi:type="xsd:string">Hello</item>'
                            + '</messageBodies>'
                            + '<recipientNumbers SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">'
                                + '<item xsi:type="xsd:string">0936XXXX</item>'
                                + '<item xsi:type="xsd:string">0918XXXX</item>'
                            + '</recipientNumbers>'
                            + '<senderNumbers SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">'
                                + '<item xsi:type="xsd:string">3000XXX</item>'
                            + '</senderNumbers>'
                            + '<encodings xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" />'
                            + '<udhs xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" />'
                            + '<messageClasses xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" />'
                            + '<priorities xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" />'
                            + '<checkingMessageIds SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:long[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">'
                                + '<item xsi:type="xsd:long">102</item>'
                                + '<item xsi:type="xsd:long">103</item>'
                            + '</checkingMessageIds>'
                    + '</ns1:enqueue>'
                + '</SOAP-ENV:Body>'
            + '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
    }
```

When I try to `console.log(client.lastRequest)` it will return this:

```
last request:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:impl="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" xmlns:intf="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue" xmlns:tns1="urn:SOAPSmsQueue" xmlns:ns1="http://magfa.com/soap/SOAPSmsQueue"><soap:Header></soap:Header><soap:Body><impl:enqueue>**<$value>**&lt;SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot; xmlns:ns1=&quot;http://WSDLPROVIDER&quot; xmlns:xsd=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot; xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns:SOAP-ENC=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/&quot; SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/&quot;&gt;&lt;SOAP-ENV:Body&gt;&lt;ns1:enqueue&gt;&lt;domain xsi:type=&quot;xsd:string&quot;&gt;XXXXXDOMAINXXXX&lt;/domain&gt;&lt;messageBodies SOAP-ENC:arrayType=&quot;xsd:string[1]&quot; xsi:type=&quot;SOAP-ENC:Array&quot;&gt;&lt;item xsi:type=&quot;xsd:string&quot;&gt;Hello&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/messageBodies&gt;&lt;recipientNumbers SOAP-ENC:arrayType=&quot;xsd:string[2]&quot; 
xsi:type=&quot;SOAP-ENC:Array&quot;&gt;&lt;item xsi:type=&quot;xsd:string&quot;&gt;09367xxxx&lt;/item&gt;&lt;item xsi:type=&quot;xsd:string&quot;&gt;09189xxxx&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/recipientNumbers&gt;&lt;senderNumbers SOAP-ENC:arrayType=&quot;xsd:string[1]&quot; xsi:type=&quot;SOAP-ENC:Array&quot;&gt;&lt;item xsi:type=&quot;xsd:string&quot;&gt;3000xxxx&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/senderNumbers&gt;&lt;encodings xsi:nil=&quot;true&quot; xsi:type=&quot;SOAP-ENC:Array&quot; /&gt;&lt;udhs xsi:nil=&quot;true&quot; xsi:type=&quot;SOAP-ENC:Array&quot; /&gt;&lt;messageClasses xsi:nil=&quot;true&quot; xsi:type=&quot;SOAP-ENC:Array&quot; /&gt;&lt;priorities xsi:type=&quot;SOAP-ENC:Array&quot; /&gt;&lt;checkingMessageIds SOAP-ENC:arrayType=&quot;xsd:long[2]&quot; xsi:type=&quot;SOAP-ENC:Array&quot;&gt;&lt;item xsi:type=&quot;xsd:long&quot;&gt;102&lt;/item&gt;&lt;item xsi:type=&quot;xsd:long&quot;&gt;103&lt;/item&gt;&lt;/checkingMessageIds&gt;&lt;/ns1:enqueue&gt;&lt;/SOAP-ENV:Body&gt;&lt;/SOAP-ENV:Envelope&gt;**</$value>**</impl:enqueue></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Is there any way to send this

Answer (score 0):

You can send raw XML using the `$xml` key:

```
let args = {
        $xml: '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://WSDLPROVIDER" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">'
                + '<SOAP-ENV:Body>'
                    + '<ns1:enqueue>'
                        + '<domain xsi:type="xsd:string">XXXXDOMAINXXXX</domain>'
                            +'<messageBodies SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">'
                            +   '<item xsi:type="xsd:string">Hello</item>'
                            + '</messageBodies>'
                            + '<recipientNumbers SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">'
                                + '<item xsi:type="xsd:string">0936XXXX</item>'
                                + '<item xsi:type="xsd:string">0918XXXX</item>'
                            + '</recipientNumbers>'
                            + '<senderNumbers SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">'
                                + '<item xsi:type="xsd:string">3000XXX</item>'
                            + '</senderNumbers>'
                            + '<encodings xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" />'
                            + '<udhs xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" />'
                            + '<messageClasses xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" />'
                            + '<priorities xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" />'
                            + '<checkingMessageIds SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:long[2]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array">'
                                + '<item xsi:type="xsd:long">102</item>'
                                + '<item xsi:type="xsd:long">103</item>'
                            + '</checkingMessageIds>'
                    + '</ns1:enqueue>'
                + '</SOAP-ENV:Body>'
            + '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
    }
```

I've referenced this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143198

as well as the `node-soap` code [where it declares an XML key](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/blob/6278bad4e216403c7482520a4cabecd9935f0c92/src/wsdl/index.ts#L55):

```
public xmlKey = '$xml';
```